# How to emulate a capacitor discharge curve using a microcontroller output pin?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitance, current-source, dac

I require a configurable amount of capacitance, without using a bank of dozens of actual capacitors and some kind of complicated switchboard, like this:

[image: capacitor decade switch]

Not only would this be an unwieldy solution, but I need to be able to change the capacitance *in software*.

I figured maybe I could emulate a capacitor discharge curve using a microcontroller. That is, the output will initially be at VCC, but quickly decay exponentially to zero, at a speed dependant on the amount of current drawn.

For example, a real capacitor would behave as shown, when the switch was opened:
[image: example of capacitor discharge curve]

I want an output (via some simple interface circuitry) that emulates such a discharge curve. I would like to be able to specify some desired capacitance, and have it produce an output consistent with the expected discharge curve of a capacitor of that value.

Possibly this could be achieved by having a real capacitor of the largest required value, but in some way affect how much charge it gets, or modify its discharging current in such a way as to simulate a smaller capacitor.

The emulated "capacitor" will only need to source current, from a starting position of "fully charged", and with its simulated cathode at ground potential. It doesn't need to simulate a charging curve, or do anything fancy like take part in a Pierce oscillator or the like.

I realise that such a solution may need to take current draw into account. Either the "simple interface circuitry" could factor this in somehow; or - failing that - I could just measure the current being drawn (e.g. using an [INA219](https://www.adafruit.com/product/904)).

Is there some feasible way of achieving this, without insanely complicated and/or expensive circuitry?

NOTE: I guess it would be acceptable to merely *approximate* the curve, using a series of discrete digital voltage levels. In other words, the output could decrease in steps, rather than being a smooth curve. Provided the resolution of these steps is fairly reasonable, it should be good enough for my purposes.

--

**EDIT:** Removed explanation of my eventual use of this device. I included the explanation to avoid accusations of the XY problem; but it has merely resulted in people obsessing over relays rather than addressing the actual question I have asked.

The question, in a nutshell, is: **How do I output an analog signal emulating the discharge curve of a specified size of capacitor?** Bearing in mind, of course, that this curve will depend on the amount of current being drawn.

Comment: Do you know any theory about conservation of reactive energy and series LC resonant oscillations. You need a diode too. You can easily simulate all of this on Falstad’s relay component with a measurements of inductance and the relay model with DCR and Cap with ESR. No need to build anything.

Comment: How - lacking a datasheet - would I determine the DCR and ESR values? Also, how would I know when the inductor in the simulation was sufficiently energised to pull the (nonexistent in the simulation) relay armature?

Comment: Why do I need a diode?

Comment: To rectify the LC oscillations

Comment: The curve is an exponential decay curve - every tick (however often your code runs) you set it to, for example, 0.9999 of its previous value.

Comment: This is definitely an X-Y problem. It is an interesting question by itself, but as far as achieving your ultimate goal of figuring out the optimal capacitance for your relay, this approach does not make sense. What is missing is a notion of how fast things need to happen. A microcontroller could simulate a capacitor if it could sense current and control a DAC which provided the output voltage. But there are speed limitations. It may also be possible to create a scaled current that discharges a small capacitor and buffer the voltage of that small cap.

Comment: @SodAlmighty:  I think part of the problem is that you can't simulate the discharge curve of a capacitor. A capacitor (ignoring leakage) by itself doesn't discharge.  You have to have a load to discharge the capacitor.  With a resistor as a load, the discharge curve is relatively simple to simulate.  But, you are trying to characterize a changing load.  You are in effect trying to determine the shape of the discharge curve.  A simulation of the discharge curve is therefore not possible.

Comment: You need to simulate capacitors with various values, not generate a voltage that follows a particular curve.

Comment: Alright. So perhaps my approach should instead be to determine what amount of current (and for what amount of time) would be required to actuate the relay? And what current was needed to keep it actuated. I could do this by successively trying greater currents and checking if the relay actuated. Then, knowing this, presumably there is a way to determine what values of capacitor and resistor would be able to provide X current for Y time before the discharge curve dropped too low...?

Answer (score 1):

A recursive difference equation

Vo(t+1)  = Vo(t) * K, where 0  < K  < 1

will provide that decaying out, as a number.

To provide the  actual voltage, use the number to set the duty cycle of a PWM
PULSE WIDTH MODULATOR, and use an RC low pass filter to remove (most of) the pulsation, and keep just the computer_controlled voltage.

=========================================

If you discharge a capacitor with a Constant Current, you produce a linear ramp.

- dV/dT = I / C, where 1uA and 1uF produce a (linear) ramp of 1 volt per second.

Comment: Thank you. But how would I go from a desired capacitance (in µF) to this K value? In addition, I believe capacitors decay at a speed dependant on the current draw. How would I factor that into the equation?

Comment: Inductive loads such as relays won't have constant currents. How can I factor the current into the equation?

Comment: @SodAlmighty microcontrollers *can't measure* the current coming out of their output pins. So you'll have to simulate that too. What is the load?

Comment: I had planned to measure the current being drawn, using e.g. an ADC.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with only a single IO pin doesn't seem feasible. What might be feasible is to do it with a combination of ADC and DAC and some external circuitry. The basic idea would be to create a digital model of the capacitor. In a loop, you would check the load current, then using that load current, calculate how much charge is lost in a single time step, then figure out how much the voltage will decrease due to that charge loss, then calculate a new voltage, update the DAC, and repeat. This would probably not do a good job simulating fast waveforms. But if the discharge takes 10's or 100's of milliseconds, then it might work.

A second, similar idea is to essentially "servo" a small cap with a scale factor. What do I mean? You would have a real capacitor connected to an amplifier with high current sinking capability. You would sense the load current and discharge the capacitor with a smaller load current. This would save you the trouble of doing any computations (it could all be analog circuitry) and would probably run faster than a digital simulation.

In the end though, this doesn't seem like a useful idea. Just an interesting one. I think it would be much easier to solve your ACTUAL problem by simple trial and error with different capacitors and an oscilloscope. But I am an empirical type of person.

Comment: An interesting idea. So, for example, if I wanted to test a 47µF capacitor on the relay, but only had an 100µF capacitor, I could buffer the voltage on the cap using (say) an op-amp, then measure how much current was being drawn from the amp and proceed to drain the cap by twice that? I would need some way of precisely partially draining a cap, though.

Comment: What I had in mind was using a smaller cap than you were simulating. For example, let's say you have a 1uF cap but you want to simulate a 10uF cap. You buffer the output of your 1uF cap to drive the load. You sense the load current and discharge the 1uF cap with a current that is 0.1x the load current. The load will see it as a 10uF cap, even though you only have a 1uF cap. So you would need some type of current amplifier with a gain of 0.1 (current attenuator). I am sure there is some simple way to set it up with op-amps. I am just too lazy to think it through.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the exponential decay is \$\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t}{RC}}\$, but this is a function of the time constant, only. It all starts from \$v(t)=\frac1C\int_t{i(t)\mathrm{d}t}\$. This shows there is a dynamic that you can't just emulate with that simple exponential formula; that formula has to include the discharge current, unless it's a constant current, in which case it reduces to what @analogsystemsrf said. That means you'll need some sort of a sensor for it. Since you are talking about mA, then an opamp with a unity resistor should be fine, but you will need that feedback to go back into the uC. This means you'll need a minimum of an ADC and proper sampling.

---

As per your comments, if the equivalent load resistance is 330 \$\Omega\$ and the capacitor is 100 \$\mu\text{F}\$, then you can model the voltage as the exponentially decaying curve:

$$V=5\text{V}\cdot\exp(-\frac{t}{330 \Omega\cdot100\mu\text{F}})$$

This formula is non-recursive, so you can calculate the voltage at any time this way. If the `exp()` is an expensive operation, then you can use @analogsystemsrf's formula, with `float k=0.36788f` (or \$\text{e}^{-1}\$) -- which will make that formula the recursive equivalent of `exp()`.

But since you are driving a relay, there will be some dynamics involving the magnetizing current and, towards the end, the moment of decoupling, which might make the above to have a shape not quite as it should be. Maybe the influence will not matter, maybe it will. But if you're aiming for precision, and since you seem to stress that:

> Bearing in mind, of course, that this curve will depend on the amount of current being drawn.

then you'll need to add a current probe and feed it back into the microcontroller and implement the discharge curve as:

$$V=5\text{V}-\frac1C\int_t{i_C(t)\text{d}t}=5-\frac{i_n+i_{n+1}}{C}$$

To illustrate what I'm talking about, this is a simulation of the concept:

[image: disharge]

In all three case, R is varying from 330 to 660 according to an \$x^2\$ curve, to simulate a dynamic resistance. `V(x)` is the voltage across an RC cell, `V(y)` would be the voltage according to the 1st formula, and `V(z)` would be the voltage according to the 2nd one. I had to add `10m` to `V(x)` otherwise `V(x)` and `V(z)` would have overlapped.

But, again, if you don't need this kind of sophistication, then use the first formula. The 2nd case is just to show that the 1st formula doesn't account for any possible dynamics, that's all.

Comment: I did initially consider just varying the voltage/current to the relay and noting when it actuated. But the relay will eventually be driven by a capacitor. How could I go from knowing how much current is required to knowing how big a capacitor is needed?

Comment: Occurs to me that the inductive properties of the coil may "cancel out" the capacitive properties of the capacitor. Is there a simple formula that I can plug required current, duration and coil inductance into, and have it output the necessary capacitance to achieve said current over said time?

Comment: If you need "indefinite time", then you need fairly large capacitors, mF or so. The relays would have considerable inductance, I'm guessing at least tens of mH (for larger relays), and tens to hundreds of Ohms (or more, if low power) -- mostly guessing, relays are not very familiar to me. E.g. C=1m, L=0.1, R=100. Which means the RC time constant is much larger than L/R. Which means the discharge will be very much dominated by the exponential formula. If you know the thresholds, that should give you an aproximation of how long the caps will hold. If this rings a bell, let me know.

Comment: Also, that cancellation you're talking about happens at resonance, but that is in an alternating environment; what you have is DC.

Comment: I have successfully actuated a 5V relay using a 100µF cap (for actuation current) and a 330Ω resistor (for holding current). I'm not sure what you mean by "indefinite time". The holding current is over an indefinite time, but the capacitor is only responsible for the actuation current. I could post my circuit for that, I guess. But my question is more "how do I output an analog signal emulating the discharge curve of a specified size of capacitor" rather than "how do I control a relay". The relay is pretty much irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I've expanded my answer on what I meant in the first place. It shows two ways to do it. No doubt there are others.

Comment: Actually the exponential curve is for constant resistance. Constant current produces a linear discharge curve.

Comment: @user253751 Did I mention constant current anywhere?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen "that formula has to include the discharge current, unless it's a constant current, in which case it reduces to what analogsystemsrf said" - analogsystemsrf said an exponential curve

Comment: @user253751 You mean out of all the answer you got stuck on a conditional (`unless`) mention that is a few words and extracted from context? Bravo!

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen What? "It's A, unless it's B, in which case do C" means that you should do C if B happens, not if A happens.

Comment: @user253751 You got stuck on that sentence,and because of that you are extracting it from the whole context and overthinking it. I won't get into a useless debate. If that's the only thing you are able to understand from above, so be it.

Comment: I am telling you that you should fix that sentence. Comments are for suggesting improvements to questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the simplest way to generate any waveform from a microcontroller pin is [Pulse-Width modulation (PWM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation#Principle):

[image]

Many microcontrollers have built-in support for this, but if yours doesn't you can emulate it in software (usually with a much longer sampling period). Connect the PWM pin from your microcontroller to a simple Low-pass filter, and then buffer the voltage on the output of that filter. You can then connect that buffered, filtered signal to wherever it needs to go.

To get the waveform you're looking for, you'll want an [exponential moving-average filter, which is exactly what a capacitor + resistor form in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization). In your microcontroller, for each time you want to update the PWM output, use:

\$ y_n ==  \$ new value to send to PWM module
\$ x_n == \$ current input to your digital filter (more on this later)
\$ y_{n-1} == \$ last value you sent to your PWM module
\$ \alpha == \$ smoothing factor (more on this later)

$$y_n =  \alpha * x_n + (1 - \alpha) * y_{n-1}$$

You want to emulate a discharge, so the very first \$y_{n-1}\$ you'll use will be equal to the maximum that your PWM module accepts (eg 65535 if your PWM is 16-bits). Your \$x_n\$ term will just be a constant: 0. That last value you'll need, \$\alpha\$, is a constant:

\$\Delta_T == \$ period between updates to the PWM module (in seconds)
\$R == \$ simulated load (in ohms)
\$C == \$ simulated capacitance (in Farads)

$$\alpha = \frac{\Delta_T}{R*C + \Delta_T}$$

Putting all of this together, you get:

$$y_n = (1 - \frac{\Delta_T}{R*C + \Delta_T}) * y_{n-1}$$

Comment: If x_n is zero, wouldn't that make the alpha redundant in the multiplication?

Comment: Yes, one of the terms using alpha would go away (but both terms depend on it), so you would be left with: y_n = (1 - alpha) * y_n-1

Comment: The exponential moving average does not give a typical `exp(-x)` curve. It could try to approximate it if the sampling frequency is very much greater than the corner frequency. If you need to implement an exact `exp(-x)`, then you have to use the impulse invariant method, which leads to precisely what analogsystemsrf and I said.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  Look at the formula that analogsystemsrf posted vs the one in my answer. They are the same thing. The only difference is mine is written with load (R), capacitance (C), and sampling period explicitly spelled out whereas his is just left as a single catch-all term (K).

Answer (score -1):

1st of all you have no design specs for performance such as a Relay or solenoid part number, Rs L, rated coil power, Must switch voltage and Must Release voltage.   the may switch depends on mfg tolerance and age.

The 2nd is your assumption that a small cap can store enough energy and the series resistor loss has a certain temperature rise that being smaller than a relay coil means it is generally hotter.

3rd Any resistor that operates at the absolute max temp, 125 to 150’C is more than boiling hot and >60’C rise above ambient is scalding derating ≈50%.

4th the hysteretic performance of relay is such that it draws more energy need to hold the contacts in order to prevent contact bounce and arc flash damage to contacts.

5th The smart solution these days is a relay/solenoid driver, which applies full rated voltage and then after a time delay , controls the current to about half or as deemed reliable depending on design.

6th the cost of a $1relay will be exceeded by the junk you are planning to added and that may reduce its performance and arc contact life.  I.e. a waste of time, unless you have a better plan with specs.

Consider the transfer of energy theorem.

7th steel core Coils can hold more energy cheaper than caps.

is that clear?

If not play with this [simulation.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YwjGAWAnC1a0npATDbB2fAZjAA5sA2FfEAVglpASICgAnJpCkbU0u3jz7gmYFgGNO3IkW7JuvfhDDQwsEAFokkIklgkE2WLFqkkvVgDc6FCEVrYbERSIgIIsR8qi12UkPaO8gGyIrAssPj8Bjy0Cu6x3B5QjhoqYBQOkbpg9uS0eghQYIzwMOXFFNilCAgsAO50tUL8cc7CrI0y0ogBvTHhjcGBTgEO4A3%202NhFwS7YLAAmTLDS4wirfUWOsAByGwikLADmWy1jji5ip20Xo7JKk3PCCBTbwmJDXHcba16TtGaLgc-CuLHcRCYh0wtjo%20AUM1cAH03kj8EjcMQkEj0uV4dgkLoELQiJ5aDjVDAkPC4tUcUjYBSqr4uqEYr8zmJIvwKB1esQekVkiovNBSDIJZLJdViqVyhV0szMLUWABlFaCphvTkiABmAEMADYAZwAppgeADzHdbiNPnRrSNMn8Jo03s58I5nTxPZgliBvU64j7Lph9rBDpNedFxoHxmJ1QVLsJ3edvAaTeb1As3R1QhRfd1XQHC-nfQR-m7y77vRWJtYkzbrVcRAlPK4fODcqI7KQiiCoUoeCiEGiMWAseOKYywAyGThfBC4dI%20yB8L1akPeCOx5jdFOVKPZ4zYAuWAAPTDt9w0dxBeBMHhFKqQWgAWwAggAdY0RhA-gB5AALN9jR-TwADVwIAdRYAB7C1tTcMAUB4ZRKRQmklWcC1WAQiBtVvexGEYFR1HIqBSWqeCAwDIU0OIGhsFfKBsx4Wi8JAJA6JEPcmJY3EqSwmVIUcbjWCIfh1HQ%20U1GKOA5IAYX1AAHfVxAASwAF31AA7cRTRYSSO3IuSACVTWNDTjR0-TDKAA) for a small 1W power Relay rated for 12V 20A contacts @277Vac resistive load rating of 5640W with an effective switch gain of 5,640. (Sure beats a transistor there)

Comment: This answer is [a] not helpful and, more importantly, [b] not an answer. Telling me that I'm an idiot and that I shouldn't do this thing is not the same as answering my question. I have successfully controlled a relay with a capacitor to enforce a short period of high current followed by an indefinite period of low holding current. So my "assumption" that it will work is borne from having done it. In addition, the resistor shown in the diagram represents a generic load, to illustrate the operation of a capacitor, and would not be present in the final product.

Comment: This "junk" I plan to add to the circuit would be one resistor and one capacitor. Hardly a greater cost than the relay. Besides, the cost of the relay is immaterial. It is the cost of *running* the relay at full current that is relevant here.

Comment: And it is precisely *because* I have no specs that I want to build this device. The purpose of the unit is to profile any relay, without specs, and determine how much current is required to [a] actuate it and [b] hold it. From that information, I want to derive such parameters as "what value of capacitor should I put in series with the high-current feed to limit its duration?"

Comment: This is a hacky way of doing things, a non engineering approach, It is possible but better to charge the capacitor with twice the voltage of the leakage R not the same. Then to model the Must hold may hold instead of anecdotal sample of 1. This has no general value to anyone

Comment: You are continuing to be unhelpful. This question has nothing to do with relays. I included the relay explanation to avoid accusations of an XY problem. My question, if you would care to re-read it, is "how do I output an analog signal emulating the discharge curve of a specified size of capacitor". If you aren't prepared to help with the question, and prefer instead to repeatedly deride me and my question, then please leave.